# Why does my Thinkpad brightness control skip steps?

Tags: 12.04, display

The problem: there are 16 brightness levels on my laptop, but pressing hotkeys `Fn+Home`, `Fn+End` adjusts brightness **3 steps** at a time (e.g. from 0 to 3, or from 15 to 12).

I find it important to notice that **at the login screen hotkeys work fine**. But after login that odd behavior appears.

Also, **if I give focus to a menu (e.g. click on *File* menu in firefox), hotkeys work fine**.

`xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown` works fine, adjusting brightness by 1 step (checked with `cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`).

I also installed `indicator-brightness` - it shows 16 leves (0-15).

I tried setting `acpi_backlight=vendor` in grub (inspired by this topic: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1909184 with similar problem). It worked in that hotkeys became working fine. But problems with OSD notification, xdotool and brightness indicator arised. So I think that it's not a right solution.

It seems that after login something interferes in the hotkeys processing scheme.
Any ideas?

## Edit (additional info)

- I made an observation that hotkeys work at hardware level - I can adjust brightness immediately after turning on my laptop (e.g. at the BIOS screen).
- After `$ killall gnome-settings-daemon` hotkeys adjust brightness by one step, but no notifications appear. Shortly `gnome-settings-daemon` recovers, and triple step issue returns.
- `acpi_listen` gives the following output (both keys sequentially):

  ```
  $ acpi_listen
  ibm/hotkey HKEY 00000080 00001010
  video LCD0 00000086 00000000
  ibm/hotkey HKEY 00000080 00001011
  video LCD0 00000087 00000000
  ```

  At this point I thought that (1) hotkeys work at hardware level; (2) `ibm/hotkey` takes care of hotkeys; (3) `video` takes care too. Thus, triple step issue appears.

  I tried blacklisting video (I expected that this will lead to a double step behavior), but nothing changed.

As a workaround, I created my own hotkeys in CompizConfig Settings Manager - as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/35096/82364), but with `--clearmodifiers` argument:

```
xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86MonBrightnessUp
xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

So now I can either use initial hotkeys or new ones for finer adjustments.

### Open questions

There was already discussion for the case with double step: [Lenovo ThinkPads, brightness function keys make two steps instead of one, looking for workaround](https://askubuntu.com/q/3834/82364):

> the hardware just does it and then also sends out a signal saying the
>   button's been pressed. Possibly you could unset the shortcut in System
>   -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts for this action?

But I am eager to know,

1. Why do I get **triple** step issue?
2. How can I unset processing this hotkeys?

I would be very grateful if someone explains it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Where do the 3 steps for 1 keypress come from?

You get three brightness steps for one keypress because:

1. The standard ACPI/video driver adjusts **step 1**
2. The `thinkpad_acpi` driver tells the BIOS to adjust **step 2** but still forwards the keypress event
3. The GNOME power daemon intercepts this keypress and tells ACPI to adjust once again **step 3**

#### 1. Disable the video driver from adjusting brightness on its own

This gets rid of one of the three steps (step 1) above.

- Open the terminal
- Type `sudo sh -c 'echo -n 0 > /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled'`
- Test, now you should have brightness control in steps of *two*
- To automatically disable this on startup, open `/etc/rc.local` in your favorite editor, and *before* the last line (`exit 0`), add:

  ```
  echo -n 0 > /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
  ```

#### 2. Recompile the `thinkpad_acpi` module to solve the double-press issue

- We have to stop `thinkpad_acpi` from adjusting the brightness via BIOS and have it *only* forward the keypress to GNOME, so that GNOME makes the only adjustment step
- This is a [known bug](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=20120503203209.GC29437%40srcf.ucam.org&forum_name=ibm-acpi-devel) which was fixed in kernel 3.4+
- To fix it for Ubuntu 12.04/Precise, we'll have patch its version of `thinkpad_acpi` and recompile it:

  1. Install the kernel headers: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
  2. Install build tools `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
  3. Make a temporary directory and change to it:

     ```
     mkdir ~/tpacpi-bright && cd ~/tpacpi-bright
     ```
  4. Download and patch the source file `thinkpad_acpi.c` from the Ubuntu Kernel git repository:

     ```
     wget -O- "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-precise.git;\
     a=blob_plain;f=drivers/platform/x86/thinkpad_acpi.c;hb=HEAD"\
     | sed -e 's/tp_features.bright_acpimode && acpi_video/acpi_video/g' \
     > thinkpad_acpi.c
     ```
  5. In the same folder where `thinkpad_acpi.c` has been downloaded, you will need a "Makefile". You can download it directly from this [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ybpnxeUT), using:

     ```
     wget -OMakefile http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ybpnxeUT
     ```

  OR paste the below into a file called `Makefile`, :

  ```
  obj-m += thinkpad_acpi.o

  all:
  	make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

  clean:
  	make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
  ```

  1. Now type `make` to create the module; you will see a `thinkpad_acpi.ko` file in the folder when done.
- Test the patched module after loading it with:

  ```
  sudo rmmod thinkpad_acpi && sudo lsmod thinkpad_acpi.ko
  ```
- If the brightness is now fixed and gives you full control, replace the stock module with the patched module:

  ```
  TPDIR=/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/platform/x86
  sudo mv $TPDIR/thinkpad_acpi.ko $TPDIR/thinkpad_acpi.ko.stock
  sudo mv ~/tpacpi-bright/thinkpad_acpi.ko $TPDIR/thinkpad_acpi.ko
  ```
- You can clean up the build folder with `make clean`; keep it around for future kernel upgrades!

Comment: thanks for you answer! Your solution completely worked for me. The only issue - brightness control doesn't work now at the login screen (I seem to understand why - because new `thinkpad_acpi` is used, but GNOME power daemon is out of business yet).

Comment: For the sake of learning, could you please tell me, is there a way to tell GNOME power daemon not to process brightness hotkeys, like we did it with `video` driver? Ubuntu provides GUI (`All Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts`) for customizing audio hotkeys (Volume Up/Down, Mute), but I didn't find where I can change or disable brightness keys.

Comment: @Andrey: you're welcome! I have a Thinkpad T520 so this was a good opportunity to fix the problem. As for the login screen, I think the way to solve that is to put the disable not in `rc.local` but in `~/.profile`, so that it only activates *after* you login. If there is a simple way to disable GNOME power daemon from processing brightness hotkeys, it will disable the OSD too (like `backlight=vendor`); doing it right may require modifying the source code...I'll try to take a look at it. Anyway, once 12.10 comes out, they will release the fixed backported kernel for 12.04, so it will work then.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem as you plus that my system always started with the screen off.

I would like to thank you for pointing me in the right direction, `acpi_backlight=vendor` did the trick for me without any of the problems you experienced.
I am using a HP G7 1116sg with hybrid graphics (Intel HD3000 *(currently only using the intel because of hybrid problems in ubuntu. I say this only because the X220 is listed as having the same graphics adapter)* / Radeon HD6870) and Ubuntu 12.04.

Just wanted to say that the grub changes worked for me without any apparent problems.

Good luck on finding a solution.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `/sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled` to `0` makes me unable to control brightness at all on my Thinkpad X230 via shortcut keys, both in tty and in xfce 4.10. I had to tell the xfce4-power-manager not to change the brightness on key events. You can do so by setting one of two hidden configuration keys. The first one is:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -n -t bool -p /xfce4-power-manager/change-brightness-on-key-events -s false
```

And the second one:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -n -t bool -p /xfce4-power-manager/show-brightness-popup -s false
```

Note: both of these settings disable the brightness popup screen on my system, but at least I get all of the 16 brightness levels back!

You can read more about this problem on [this page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1083140) and on [the bottom of this page](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/preferences).

Answer (score 0):

In my Lenovo S205 laptop I had this issue where the both the video driver and gnome adjusted the brightness.

But my experience disabling the `brightness_switch_enabled` property is that gnome is slow and seems racy when updating the backlight --- for instance if I leave the keys down for a couple of seconds and then let go, gnome still takes 5-10s to process the events.

So instead I prefer to let the video driver do the adjustments, and stop gnome from doing them.

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper
```

Disabling the `gsd-backlight-helper` did the trick for me. I crawled the internets and there doesn't seem to be a user-visible option to do the same.

I did lose the brightness OSD but now brightness changes are processed instantly, and as a bonus I still have brightness control on the tty.